# Modify notifications on a running build in jenkins

Tags: jenkins

I occasionally want to get notified when a particular jenkins job that is building finishes.  Is there any way to do this?

Scripting it through the API would be fine.  I already have the jenkins IRC bot that notifies me of many things, so if I could just dynamically modify the running job build, that would be enough to do what I want -- I'm just having a hard time finding how to accomplish that.

Comment: Are you aware of the ability to send an email notification based on pre-defined rules? Look into the following plugin: https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin

Comment: Yes, but I'm wanting to change this after the job has already started.  like "subscribe me to this build when it finishes".

Comment: AFAIK, you cannot change a job's config while it's running. I would try to use a post-build step to check for an external resource status (like a file containing an action by text) and running an action based on the content of the file. The external file can be modified while the build is running, so when the post-build is executed, it will follow the logic defined based on the content of the file.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I was looking for, if you put that in an answer, I'll mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, you cannot change a job's config while it's running.

Here is an idea: Use a post-build step to check for an external resource status (like a file containing an action by text) and running an action based on the content of the file.
The external file can be modified while the build is running, so when the post-build is executed, it will follow the logic defined based on the content of the file.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use email notifier, It will send you an email 
https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Email-ext+plugin